# How can I calculate GPS DoP (Dilution of Precision) using iPhone sensor data?

Tags: ios, iphone, gps, sensors

I am gathering data from an iPhone 6 using the SensorLog app. Other devices offer the output of GPS_DOP (GPS Dilution of Precision) which I use in my algorithms. However, SensorLog gives *locationVerticalAccuracy* and *locationHorizontalAccuracy*. I want to classify my data based on [this rating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilution_of_precision_(GPS)#Meaning_of_DOP_Values).

Is the *GPS_DOP* the same as*locationVerticalAccuracy* or should I calculate it somehow?

**Otherwise**,

is there a rough calculation of DoP depending on metric errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No the GPS_DOP is not the same as horizontal accuracy estimate. DOP is a unit less factor, showing the factor to the standard deviation.
Example: If the standard deviation is 3m, a DOP (or better hdop) of 2.0 means  about 3 * 2 = 6m.
Further the table you linked is outdated, since it was valid for GNSS receivers that use the american GPS only. The iPhone6 used GPS + the Russian GLONASS resulting in a much better DOP now as showed in that table. (If you would have access to the DOPs)

Consider using the horizontalAccuracy in meters only.
For iPhone6:

```
3m is very  good
6m is good
10m not so good
> 20m bad
```

For  most Applications vertical accuracy is not used, therefore even when using DOP values the H-DOP is used.